# Obtener un solo registro de un join de tres tablas?

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM ct_factura,ct_dosificacion,ct_contrato_cuenta
WHERE ct_contrato_cuenta.n_id_factura = ct_factura.n_id
and ct_dosificacion.n_id = ct_factura.n_id_dosificacion
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta, en donde ct_factura y ct_dosificacion devuelven un solo registro, sin embargo el join entre ct_factura y ct_contrato_cuenta, devuelve mas de una registro, como hago para que solo hagan el join y me devuelva un solo registro entre estas dos tablas: ct_factura y ct_contrato_cuenta,gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes intentar convinando el order by y el limit para limitar a el join que te regresa mas de un registro

Comment: Si cuando haces el join te duplica las filas(rows) es por que en una tabla tienes un valor y en otra 2 o mas, tienes que ver cual es el registro que es diferente en tus dos o mas rows y trabajar con este ya sea  sumarlo, contarlo, colocar el maximo o el minimo, y posteriormente agrupar con group by, pero identifica primero tu informaciòn, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estimados ya pude resolver la consulta:

```
     SELECT ct_medicion_grupo.v_nombre,count(*)
              FROM ct_factura
           inner join (select distinct cuenta.n_id_factura id_fac, cuenta.n_id_contrato id_con 
                           from ct_contrato_cuenta cuenta
                           inner join ct_factura on ct_factura.n_id = cuenta.n_id_factura) contrato_cuenta on contrato_cuenta.id_fac = ct_factura.n_id
           inner join ct_contrato on ct_contrato.n_id = contrato_cuenta.id_con
           inner join ct_propiedad on ct_propiedad.n_id = ct_contrato.n_id_propiedad
           inner join ct_propiedad_division_geo on ct_propiedad_division_geo.n_id_propiedad = ct_propiedad.n_id
           inner join ct_division_geo on ct_division_geo.n_id = ct_propiedad_division_geo.n_id_division_geo
           inner join ct_medicion_grupo_division_geo on  ct_medicion_grupo_division_geo.n_id_division_geo = ct_division_geo.n_id                
           inner join ct_medicion_grupo on ct_medicion_grupo.n_id = ct_medicion_grupo_division_geo.n_id_medicion_grupo
           and ct_factura.n_id  IN (
           select ct_factura.n_id
           from ct_lectura 
           inner join ct_ruta_asignacion on ct_ruta_asignacion.n_id = ct_lectura.N_ID_RUTA_ASIGNACION 
           left join ct_factura on ct_factura.V_PERIODO = to_char(to_date(ct_lectura.N_MES||'/'||ct_lectura.N_ANIO,'mm/yyyy'),'MON/yyyy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH') 
           and ct_lectura.N_CUENTA = ct_factura.v_cuenta 
           and ct_factura.C_CODIGO_FACTURA_TIPO = 'MES' 
           where ct_ruta_asignacion.n_id_cronograma_medicion_grupo in(5456,5470,5458,5459,5460,5461,5462,5463,5464,5465,5466,5467,5468,5469,5457) 
           and (ct_factura.n_id is not null or ct_lectura.c_estado = 7))
           group by ct_medicion_grupo.v_nombre;
```

Gracias de todos modos por toda la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica tus datos, te mando un ejemplo de un group by.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') is not null drop table #temp1;
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') is not null drop table #temp2;

create table #temp1 (a int);
create table #temp2 (b int, c int);

insert #temp1 values(1);
insert #temp2 values(1,1);
insert #temp2 values(1,2);

--- en la tabla #temp2 se encuentran 2 registros en 1 por lo cual se duplica la información, 
--- por lo cual si quieres solo un registro tienes que trabajar el registro que es diferente en este caso se suma

select *
from #temp1 a
inner join #temp2 b
on a.a = b.b;

select a, sum(c) suma
from #temp1 a
inner join #temp2 b
on a.a = b.b
group by a;
```